# Do I need a 23c or 25c?

Tags: tire

I have fitted a 28mm clincher tyre on my road bike, which is too high. Will a 25mm fit?   It had 23mm on previously.

Wheel drags on the top with 28mm.

My bike is a Claud Butler *Converse* with narrow racing wheels. Wheel will roll but I have to push it to make it turn. I may have to try a 25mm and chance it.  Will the 25mm be slightly lower, if so it may work!

Comment: Some frames or forks can take a 25mm tire, some can't. We don't know what bike you have so we can't tell you. Also tire sizes are not very consistent between manufacturers or models. Put the 23s on, and see how much clearance you have to estimate if 25s will fit.

Comment: And if the previous tire is worn, allow some extra room for thicker tread on new tire.

Comment: When I installed a tire which was too high, (in my case a 20" wheel,) 28 mm instead of a 23 mm, the wheel did not turn at all. I happened to have a 25 mm at hand which did fit. So you might be lucky but unless you test it, you can not be sure.

Comment: Uh, measure the clearance, and understand that the "width" measure is an *approximation* of the tire's cross-sectional diameter.  How much is the 28 oversize?  Will a reduction of 3mm be sufficient to provide clearance?

Comment: Oh, come on. How could we possibly know? "This pair of trousers is too small for me. Will the next size up fit?"

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what bike you have and what tyres you're planning to use, it'd be hard for anyone to tell you if they have the same combination and if it works.  For example, I have a B'Twin Triban 3 (White one.) with Fulcrum Racing 7 wheelset and currently Continental Gatorskins 700x25c which fit with about 3 or 4mm clearance.

Having said that, if 28c drags (Massively or just a little?) and 23c was what you used previously (That's what my B'Twin had on it originally.) then there's a good chance 25c will work with a few mm clearance.